# Why Angular's request header modification throws an option 401 error

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I want to modify the angular `HttpRequest`'s header, but an OPTIONS 401 error is thrown in chrome.

I use Angular 7 client which runs on http://localhost:4200 and .net core 2.1 which runs on http://localhost:5000

The problem I face is this:

If I do not use the `httpInterceptor` (which means I do not modify the `httpRequest` header) the request is proceeding to the server and return the value.

But if I try to modify the headers, I get the following error:

> Options http://localhost:5000/api/value/2 401 (Unautorized)
>   Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/values/2:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>   'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed to access.
>   The response had Http status code 401.

which is a bit odd, because if I clone the `httpRequest` that the Chrome creates, when I do not modify the headers, the request succeed. But when I try to modify it, it fails.

Furthermore, I did try to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the request. But yet again I receive the same error.

I use `HttpInterceptor` to modify the `HttpRequest` headers.

```
export class HeaderInterpreter  implements HttpIntterceptor {

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    If (req instanceof HttpRequest && localStorage.getItem("token")){
        const modReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`)
        })
        return next.handle(modReq);
    }
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

}

In server side I did the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IserviCollection services)
{
...
services.addCors();
...
services.addMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   ...

   app.UseCors(builder => 
      builder.withOrigins("http://localhost:4200"))
      .allowAnyHeader();

   ...

   app.UseMvc();
}
```

I also used `withCredentials: true` on the Angular's `http.get` function and windows authentication on the server

Comment: The browser itself refuses to make the call to the .NET Core app. You need to configure CORS on the Angular *server*. Your client is loaded from the Angular server on port 4200 and has the CORS headers provided by it. That server needs to specify it's OK to call `localhost:5000` too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the angular dev server is the wrong place to configure cors. The client part should be ok here. SHMT - do you use authentication? I guess something in your mvc app blocks the options call.

Comment: I do use windows authentication. I google this issue the other day, and i believe i find the problem, but not the solution. Because i add an authorize header, the chrome sends a preflight option request(which been sent without windows authentication header) while the server only allow authenticated users. I saw few workaround in old asp.net but couln't find any solution in .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occured because of several reasons:

First, I use both windows authentication and a jwt token, so I enabled the windows authentication using "UseHttpSys" on program.cs.

Second, Because I used both windows authentication and jwt token, I couldn't send the jwt token on the authorize header, insetead I sent it on a custom header of my own.

third, becuase I sent a request with an authorize header, Chrome sent a preflight request, for Cors purposes. But because the preflight request(a.k.a options) has not been sent with the authorize header, the server  rejected it (becuase it grant permissions to only authenticated users). so I needed to enable annonymous access on the server.

forth, I used a middleware to check if the request is preflight, if it doesn't I checkek if the reuest is from an authenticated user. (because I allowed annonymous access, chrome first sends an unauthenticated request, and when it was rejected by the middleware, Chrome resends an authenticated request).

see reference https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60#issuecomment-262880489